# How to add a sort query to my StructuredQueryBuilder before talking to Marklogic

Tags: java, json, search, marklogic

I am trying to add a sort/ordering query.

At my java:

```
StructuredQueryBuilder qb = new StructuredQueryBuilder();
QueryDefinition queryDef = qb.and(qb.value(qb.jsonProperty("status"), "Active"));               
SearchHandle resultsHandle = new SearchHandle();        
queryManager.setPageLength(PAGE_SIZE_TEN);
int start = PAGE_SIZE_TEN * (pageNumber - 1) + 1;
queryManager.search(queryDef, resultsHandle, start);
```

The above will return the resultsHandle with 10 json files found for each page specified for the variable "start", with status "Active".

My question is how do I include a sorting query like maybe something along the line of the following:

```
QueryDefinition queryDef = qb.and(qb.value(qb.jsonProperty("status"), "Active"), 
                                  qb.sort?(qb.jsonProperty("dateCreated"));
```

I want it to get me the 1st 10 json files in order of latest date. It is too late to do a Comparator after getting the result, as the result returns a random 10 json files not in any particular order.

A few samples of the json files will look as such:
1.json

```
[
 {
  "id":"1",
  "dateCreated":"2017-10-01 12:00:00",
  "status":"Active"
  "body":"This is a test"
 }
]
```

2.json

```
[
 {
  "id":"2",
  "dateCreated":"2017-10-02 12:00:00",
  "status":"Active"
  "body":"This is a test 2"
 }
]
```

I realized there's a enum StructuredQueryBuilder.Ordering, how do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

`StructuredQueryBuilder.Ordering` is specifically for use with `near-query` and is unrelated to what you want to do. You need to use query options to define a sort order for your search results. See the `sort-order` query option:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_44212

Options can be pre-defined and installed on MarkLogic and then referenced in your search, or you can define them at runtime and combine them with your structured query in a combined query.

- Predefined: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/query-options#chapter
- Dynamic: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_76144

Comment: Is there another way if my website is local and does not connects to the internet, this way i won't be able to use the following: "<options xmlns=\"http://marklogic.com/appservices/search\">"

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. That is just an XML namespace declaration. It does not imply connecting to the internet.